# Multiple items visible and invisible depending on observable

Tags: javascript, css, knockout.js

I have two items that should be visible only when a given observable evaluates to false, and one item that should be visible when the same item evaluates to true. It works fine if I only have two items whose visibility depends on the observable. However, when a third item is introduced, it stops working.

ViewModel:

```
var viewModel = {
editable: ko.observable(false),
edit: function () {
    this.editable(true);
},
delete: function () {
    this.editable(true);
},
cancel: function () {
    this.editable(false);
},
save: function () {
    this.editable(false);
}
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

A fiddle is available here: http://jsfiddle.net/mupersan82/Y6eKS/10/

The fiddle is working. Uncomment one of the "button" items to see the problem.

Can anyone identify what the problem is?

Regards, Anders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`delete` is a Javascript operator and therefore a reserved word (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete). Renaming the function fixes it:

```
var viewModel = {
    editable: ko.observable(false),
    edit: function () {
        this.editable(true);
    },
    remove: function () {
        this.editable(true);
    },
    cancel: function () {
        this.editable(false);
    },
    save: function () {
        this.editable(false);
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

(fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y6eKS/11/)